# Ionic tabs re-init component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-tabs

I am using `ion-tabs` and `ion-tab` components for `Ionic 3`. Currently, when user switches between tabs the component in the tab `<ion-tab [root]="SomeComponent"></ion-tab>` is only initialized when the user switches to it first time. After that ,there is no more call of the `ionViewDidLoad` or `ngOnInit`. The question is: Is it possible to destroy the component on tab change and then initialize it again later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **ionViewWillEnter** and **ionViewWillEnter** lifecycle event on your page.

You can put the correct code in that method to **initialize or destroy** necessary things on your page

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/